# A group of disabled people are sent to explore a distant planet due to their toughness and ability to survive

Tags: story-identification, soft-sci-fi, pulp

It's an old pulp sci-fi novel of my dad's that I read in the 80s that I think came from the late 60s to early 70s.

The basic plot was that a hazardous mission to explore a distant planet was crewed with "freaks", people who had suffered accidents or had genetic abnormalities, and as a result were tougher and stronger than regular folk. The leader was a guy with no arms, whose face could light up after exposure to a dangerous chemical. Another guy had no legs, but massively strong arms. There was a fat woman who wore an acid filled suit to retard the constant growth of her flesh.

That's all I can remember about it as I read it 30 or so years ago, but it made a strong impression on me.

Comment: "face could like up after exposure"? Could you clarify that because I can't make sense of it.

Comment: Ah... "light up", perhaps.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots I mean "light up" not "like up" and have corrected my post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect that this is *[Address: Centauri](https://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/gutenberg.org/5/0/7/3/50736/50736-h/50736-h.htm)* by F.L. Wallace, an expansion of his story "Accidental Flight" which first appeared in the magazine *Galaxy Science Fiction* in 1952. From [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address:_Centauri):

> The novel concerns people with incurable injuries and defects (biocompensators) who volunteer for the first interstellar flight.

....

> - Docchi - Formerly an electrochemical engineer, an accident mangles him and tosses him into a tank of cold lighting fluid. He survived but the accident left him armless. The fluid also permeated his system, causing him to glow.
> - Nona - Essentially a living computer. Cannot comprehend spoken language.
> - Jordan - Half man, his lower torso was severed in an accident.
> - Anti (Antoinette) - Ballet dancer who crashed on Venus. Her body was permeated by a Venusian fungus that causes a symbiotic overgrowth of tissue.
> - Doctor Cameron - Medical doctor and administrator for Handicap Haven.
> - Maureen - Her body lacks the glands to produce male hormones.
> - Jeriann - Unable to drink. Gets fluid through absorption capsules.

As with most classic sci-fi, it's been released with a variety of covers, but here is one of them:

[image: Book cover]

Comment: For what it's worth, I found it by searching on *science fiction short story exploration  suit acid "no arms"* in Google. The Internet Archive copy of the issue of Galaxy Science Fiction's release of "Accidental Flight" is the first result, although I'd clicked on a few results and searched for keywords before seeing that one was a good match (IA's archive copies tend to have a lot of scanning errors). A second search on the title and author found the nicer Project Gutenberg text and the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Yes! That's the one - when I saw the name Docchi, it all came flooding back! Thank you so much!

Comment: James Alan Gardner's [*League of Peoples*](http://www.amazon.com/Expendable-League-Peoples-Bk-1/dp/038079439X) series also has the theme of deformed/semi-disabled people selected as "expendable crew members" for dangerous missions.